# Use Dwolla for peer to peer money transfer in ionic 1 app

Tags: ionic-framework, payment-gateway, p2p, dwolla

I'm building an ionic app, which requires transferring money from one user to other. And each transaction will probably be somewhere between 500$-1000$

I looked up some online money transferring services like Paypal, Stripe etc, and they have great documentation but most of them have decent amount of transaction fee (2.5-3%). Since transactions in my app are not small, my end users will be paying extra fees of 20-30$ each transaction.

Then I came across Dwolla (https://developers.dwolla.com/guides/transfer-money-between-users/?utm_source=seo&utm_medium=seo&utm_campaign=seo-money-transfer-api). It looks good and they have good documentation for using with node. But I can't find any helpful article to use with ionic.

Has anybody tried integrating Dwolla with ionic-1? Or is there any other online money transfer service, which has good documentation for integrating with ionic and has less or no transaction fees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dwolla unfortunately does't feature any sample code using Ionic since the primary interaction with Dwolla is between your backend server and the Dwolla API. In general, API calls should be made by your backend server(s), which should securely store your API credentials and manage other business logic surrounding payments.

Since Dwolla offers a white-labeled experience, it's really up to you how the payment experience is presented to the user, and how that is technically achieved between your backend and your mobile client. Although I don't have first hand experience in working with Ionic, there may be others in the Dwolla developer community who have. If interested, free to cross post your question on the [API support forums](https://discuss.dwolla.com/c/api-support)!

Comment: Thanks! That make sense and APIs are easy to use as well. Only thing  I'm not sure is what would be the recommended practice to refresh access tokens for white-label application. May be have a cron-job running at my server that generates the token every hour and my application users can request that token to become a customer in Dwolla app or add a funding source to their existing account or even make a transfer.